# Makefile fails becuase of an -include directive

Tags: makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html#Include):

> If you want 'make' to simply ignore a makefile which does not exist
>   or cannot be remade, with no error message, use the '-include' directive
>   instead of 'include', like this:
>
> ```
>  -include FILENAMES...
> ```
>
> This acts like 'include' in every way except that there is no error
>   (not even a warning) if any of the FILENAMES (or any prerequisites of
>   any of the FILENAMES) do not exist or cannot be remade.

Now, version 1 of my makefile, is:

```
all:
    @:

-include x


x:: phony
    true

x:: phony
    false

.PHONY: phony
```

Running, I get:

```
true
false
makefile:11: recipe for target 'x' failed
make: *** [x] Error 1
```

Oops! Shouldn't it just ignored -included (sincluded) makefiles, that can not be remade w/o errors?

And, version 2 of my makefile, reads:

```
all:
    @:

-include x


x:: phony
    false

x:: phony
    true

.PHONY: phony
```

Running, I get:

```
false
make: *** No rule to make target 'x'.  Stop.
```

This is simply outrageous, for the following:

1. As in version 1, although the -included (sincluded) makefile can not be remade, it should simple be **ignored**, as explicitly said in the docs, cited above.
2. But more so is questionable, the misleading debugging-message given by Make:

   > make: *** No rule to make target 'x'.  Stop.

   Because, yeah, there **is** a rule to make this target. In fact, there is a rule for **each** double-colon file of this target (`x`).

   So, even if Make wants to "fail" this build (why?), it should **NOT** output garbage!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here isn't that the `include` isn't being ignored. Its that you haven't specified a correct rule to make `x`.

If you run the simple `makefile` below you will see that it runs without error even when the file `x` is not present and can't be included.

```
-include x

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo 'Ignoring include error'
```

I've supplied a corrected version of your `makefile` below. **Note**: how I have used `.PHONY` and removed the duplicate rule for `x`.

```
all:
    @:

-include x

.PHONY: x

x:: phony
    true
```